# Reduxの言葉、日本語で何という？

Tags: reactjs, redux

Reactの開発をし、Reduxも使っています。ドキュメンテーションを書いている中でReduxについて書いているのですが、下記の言葉を日本語で何というのか分かりません。

- React
- Redux
- Actions
- Action Creator
- Reducer

ただ「アクション」とかのようなカタカナの言葉になるのでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React, Reduxは固有名詞で翻訳はできません。
Actions、Action Creator等についてもReduxで使うActionであり、Reduxで使うAction Creatorなので、日本語の単語への翻訳(活動、アクション生成器とか縮約器)はなじまないでしょう。見たことはないし、違和感があります。

- React →そのまま
- Redux →そのまま
- Actions →そのままか、アクション、意訳すれば「Reduxのアクション」
- Action Creator→そのままか、アクションクリエイター、意訳すれば「Reduxのアクションクリエイター」
- Reducer→そのままか、意訳すれば「ReduxのReducer」

などが妥当なのではないでしょうか。